# Edit and delete permissions

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there a way to remove the Edit and Del link on related lists like Activity History when users have rights to Edit and Delete?[image]

Comment: I believe if any user doesn't have **edit and delete** permission then he will not see these links on related list.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no configuration option to remove the delete link that appears on the Activities HIstory related list.
Check out this idea on the IdeaExchange.  One of the comments also points you to Task Manager, an application on the AppExchange.  I haven't used it, but it claims to provide security on completed task deletion.
I think the only thing you can do is recreate the list using VF page.  You might be able to achieve something useful by using CRUD permissions for the user profiles.

Hope this Helps,Thanks